# How can you display an error message when the Create button is clicked before the Email verification is completed?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

In the custom policy "SignUpSignIn" of the Starter pack you have the "Send verification" button and the "Create" button in the same screen.

When you press the "Create" button without first verifying your email address the button doesn't respond and no error message is displayed.

How can I present an error message when the user presses the Create button but hasn't completed the email verification?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way of presenting an error in B2C, however there are two possible workarounds:

1. Localisation - You modify the localisation strings to make it more obvious that the user has to click the "Send Verification" button before continuing. You could change the verification intro text to "Before you can create your account, we need to you verify your email for security reasons".
2. Javascript - You could use custom javascript enabled templates (currently in [private preview](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15493536-add-support-for-javascript-inside-the-custom-ui-br)) to modify the behaviour of the "Create" button such that it errors if the email hasn't been verified yet.